# Why do all the widgets not properly inherit Qt Style Sheet from QApplication?

Tags: c++, css, qt

At the very beginning of the program, I've fully loaded the QSS files into the QApplication with:

```
((QApplication*) QApplication::instance())->setStyleSheet(newStyleSheet);
```

And this really works fine on most of the widgets.
But when coming to Property Selector, it fails. For instance:

```
Label#GidParam QLabel[Empty="true"] {
  border-image: url(:/some.png);
}
Label#GidParam QLabel[Empty="false"] {
  border:1px solid rgb(61,138,244);
}
```

I do refresh the styleSheet with:

```
label->setProperty("Empty", true);
label->setStyleSheet(label->styleSheet());
```

nothing change.

However, I find that it takes effect if I set styleSheet again in the app main window when it is being created. As to what is said in the book, C++ GUI Programming with Qt4, that `QApplication::setStyleSheet() sets a style sheet for the entire application`, I'm really confused now.